`git config --global color.ui auto` does not seem to be colorizing output in terminal
I would like the console to show colorized output for git functions like git status as opposed to just black and white output.
I have tried to use git config actions to set up colorized option and git config --list shows color.ui = true. `git config --global color.ui auto' does not seem to do anything. I am using git version 2.45.1 on an older MacBook running macOS 12.7.5
init.defaultbranch=main
color.ui=true
color.diff=auto
pull.rebase=false
core.excludesfile=/Users/phillipbaker/.gitignore_global
core.editor=code --wait
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true



I would like the console to show colorized output for git functions like git status.

Git offers a few options to customize the color of its commands. If you wish to color differently git status, then you need to enable the variable color.status, not color.diff. From the section Colors in Git of the official documentation:

If you want to be more specific about which commands are colored and how, Git provides verb-specific coloring settings. Each of these can be set to true, false, or always: color.branch, color.diff, color.interactive, color.status.

In your case, the sequence of commands would be:
# customize colors only when commands are directed to the terminal
git config --global color.ui auto

# enabling custom colors for git status
git config --global color.status true

# defining the foreground and background colors for git status
git config --global color.status.meta "magenta white bold"

Instead, if you actually wanted to customize git diff instead of git status due to a typo, you can run the same commands and replace color.status with color.diff.
